# Finding the largest absolute difference in a list

Tags: python

I'm moving away from map, reduce and filter in favour of list comprehensions. I like list comps but I feel like this is getting on the unreadable side.

Is this the most idiomatic way of achieving this? Is it easy enough to read?

```
int_list = [-1,-3,5,7]

absolute_diffs = [max( [abs( int_2 ) - abs( int_1 ) for int_2 in int_list] ) for int_1 in int_list]

print max( absolute_diffs )
```

Comment: It's not mandatory (unless you are writing code for Google), but the [Google Python style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html) is a good reference for what readable Python code should look like.  And it explicitly forbids [nested list comprehensions](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#List_Comprehensions).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A more idiomatic and readable solution would be to use [`itertools.combinations(list, 2)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to take all pairs.

```
max(abs(a) - abs(b) for a, b in itertools.combinations(int_list, 2))
```

However, that is O(*n*<sup>2</sup>). A smarter O(*n*) solution would be to subtract the minimum absolute value from the maximum absolute value.

```
absolutes = [abs(elem) for elem in int_list]
print max(absolutes) - min(absolutes)
```

Comment: I wish I could give you an additional up-vote for the alternative algorithm suggestion. For the oblivious: OP's algorithm runs in O(n²) while 200_success' suggestion runs in O(n).

Comment: Yes @DavidFoerster I've changed my code completely based on the suggested algorithm, much nicer.

Comment: You should explicitly add the algorithm you described, since the OP has mapped the list twice for nothing in his edited question (before the rollback).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I've revised the answer to be explicit.

Comment: I was more thinking about this: `l = [abs(elem) for elem in int_list] ; print max(l) - min(l)` where absolute values are calculated only once, that was the reason of my previous comment.

Comment: OK that indeed looks better.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, purely functional style approach that builds on `itertools.combinations` too is this:

```
max(itertools.starmap(operator.sub, itertools.combinations(map(abs, int_list), 2)))
```